# redis-trib.rb is no longer available but redis-cli --cluster create throws unrecognized option error

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am attempting to create a new redis cluster on the docker swarm using redis 4.0.11. The closest tutorial I have found was this one: https://get-reddie.com/blog/redis4-cluster-docker-compose/

The problem I am having is this like all other tutorials use the ruby redis-trib.rb script to create the cluster after discovering all of the nodes and this guy seems to be no longer supported:

```
| WARNING: redis-trib.rb is not longer available!
| You should use redis-cli instead.
|
| All commands and features belonging to redis-trib.rb have been moved
| to redis-cli.
| In order to use them you should call redis-cli with the --cluster
| option followed by the subcommand name, arguments and options.
|
| Use the following syntax:
| redis-cli --cluster SUBCOMMAND [ARGUMENTS] [OPTIONS]
|
| Example:
| redis-cli --cluster create 172.22.0.3:6379 172.22.0.5:6379 172.22.0.7:6379 172.22.0.2:6379 172.22.0.6:6379 172.22.0.4:6379 --cluster-replicas 1
|
| To get help about all subcommands, type:
| redis-cli --cluster help
```

But yet when I attempt to use the recommended command I get an error:

```
# redis-cli --cluster create 172.22.0.3:6379 172.22.0.5:6379 172.22.0.7:6379 172.22.0.2:6379 172.22.0.6:6379 172.22.0.4:6379 --cluster-replicas 1
Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--cluster'
# redis-cli --cluster help
Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--cluster'
```

Ideas?

Comment: This is almost certainly the result of an older version of redis-cli. What does `redis-cli --version` yield?

Comment: redis-cli 4.0.11

Answer (score 4):

redis-cli 4.0.11 hasn't --cluster option.

use following ways:

1. download https://github.com/antirez/redis/archive/unstable.zip
2. make
3. use redis-cli in src/redis

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant to say :)

Answer (score 0):

They have changed the docs, with the previous version you had to do it with the `redis-trib.rb` file as you said.

The easiest way to do it, is to download to your server the previous `redis-trib.rb` ([link](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/4.0/src/redis-trib.rb)) and run this command:

```
./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 \
127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005
```

before you do it make sure you have installed ruby.

If you have any questions let me know :)
Good luck!